# ApacheURLLister in Android split String

Tags: java, android

I'm using `ApacheURLLister` to view list of mp3 files. I need to show only the file name but `ApacheURLLister` showing the full path like "http://server.com/a/song.mp3". I need to show only "song.mp3".

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listAudio);
    new getAudiofromServer().execute();
    new downloadAudioFromServer().execute();

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
              String url = null;

              Object o = myList.get(position);

              url = o.toString().replace(" ", "%20").trim();      
              play = (PlaySongAsy) new PlaySongAsy(url).execute();
       }
     });
 }

 private void playSong(String songPath) {
     try {
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(songPath);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
    }        
}

private class downloadAudioFromServer extends
        AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        int count;

        try {
            URL url1 = new URL("http://server/Mora/");
            URLConnection conexion = url1.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();
            int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url1.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Sounds/");
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / lenghtOfFile));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class getAudiofromServer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting File list from server, Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        try {
            urlAudio = new URL("http://server/Mora/");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ApacheURLLister lister1 = new ApacheURLLister();
        try {
            myList = lister1.listAll(urlAudio);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                myList);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        mListView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
}

class PlaySongAsy extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    String baseURL;

    public PlaySongAsy(String baseURL) {
        this.baseURL = baseURL;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                playSong(baseURL);
            }
        }.start();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using the standard `ArrayAdapter` and layout which will just convert each URL into a string and display in the the list hence you have the full URL in the list.

Instead created your own adapter and use the `URL.getFile()` which just returns the file name like `URL.getFile()` and you can keep the whole url saved in the layout view with `setTag()` so on click method you can still retrieve the whole url and do the rest of the processing.

Try this tutorial which explains the `ArrayAdapter` usage in simple way:

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Comment: I have put the tutorial link in the answer now. Its very easy to follow. On a sidenote extending `ArrayAdapter` and showing list data is by far the simplest among other adapters. The example link also explains why you are getting the full URL in default `ArrayAdapter` as it simply does `toString()` of all the object.